# Insert into XML from HTML Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I need to insert sample data into SQl server.
But i should use HTML,Javascript,JQuery,Ajax,XML only.
I can't use asp.net or php programming  languages , because i will not use IIS for this project.

Is there any option to do this?

Hi,Is possible to connect to SQL from XML page.

Comment: Why not lighthttpd, nginx or XAMPP for php?

Comment: How can you use Ajax if there is no server to answer the request?

Comment: sorry siidheesh, i can't know about these,and also requirement is that insert data into DB from HTML page

Comment: hi sune,by creating Endpoint in SQl server and call that service url using Ajax and Json method.

Comment: Daniel,to find out is there any solution?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a server side page to handle your ajax request where it will read the data coming from ajax request and send to the db.

If you do not want to use IIS, you can think about PHP as your server page which works on `Apache` server.